# finding sequential in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am going to find sequential string of numbers in string which starts from 1. For example I have this string.

```
"456000123456009123456780001234000"
```

Here sequential strings would be

```
"123456", "12345678", "1234"
```

How can I get above result using Javascript efficiently?
The code looks like this.

```
findSequential("456000123456009123456780001234000");
//expected output
"123456", "12345678", "1234"
```

***note: "1" itself is not sequential, for example:

```
"3938139" - has no sequence
"39381249" - has "12"
```

With any language's solution would be appreciated but prefer Javascript or C.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Generally you'll get better responses/guidance/feedback from the community if you include what you have tried already.

Comment: Why not start with 0? 0123456

Comment: How do you define “sequential”? Should consecutive numbers always increase by +1? Should they always be integers? Why do you have a space separated string rather than an array? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So what do you need? Numbers, integers, or digits? Do you have any attempt at an implementation of this `findSequential` function?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I want to get sequential string from original string as you can see in description.

Comment: @Bojan Yes, I know what the question says, but it’s still not clear. Your examples only include integers from 1 to 9 (i.e. digits) and your examples only include successor sequences. You don’t explain what should happen with larger or smaller integers (e.g. 11 or −3) and what should happen with numbers that aren’t integers; there is no clear **definition** of “sequential”. You only explain that sequences should start with 1. And again, this question would benefit from an attempt at writing a `findSequential` function yourself.

Comment: I only focus on 1~9 numbers. numbers bigger than 10 and smaller than 0 are ignored

Comment: Another question is: what about `1` itself? Is that a sequence? Are `1212` two sequences? Are `11` two sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop should be able to achieve this. In JavaScript:

```js
function findSequential(s) {
    const res = []
    let current = []
    let num = 1
    for(let char of s) {
      if (char == num) {
        current.push(char)
        num ++
      } else if (current.length > 1) {
        res.push(current.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur, ''))
        if (char == 1) {
          current = ['1']
          num = 2
        } else {
          current = []
          num = 1
        }
      } else if (current.length === 1) {
        current = []
        num = 1
      }
    }
    if (current.length > 1) {
      res.push(current.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur, ''))
    }
    return res
}

console.log(findSequential('31234121'))
```

Comment: @user4642212 Thanks - have fixed for cases where the string ends in a sequence.

Comment: And it doesn’t find the second sequence in `findSequential("1212");` (depends on the OP’s definition of “sequential”, of course).

Comment: You're right @user4642212 - I've fixed this case as well.

Comment: @DanielElkington Nice effort.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```js
function findSequential(str) {
  const res = [];
  let currentHigh = 0;
  for (let char of str) {
    if (+char === currentHigh + 1) {
      currentHigh++;
    } else if (currentHigh > 0) {
      res.push(buildSequence(currentHigh))
      currentHigh = +char === 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  if (currentHigh > 0) {
    res.push(buildSequence(currentHigh));
  }
  return res;
}

function buildSequence(max) {
  if (max <= 1) { return "1"; }
  else { return buildSequence(max - 1) + max; }
}

console.log(findSequential("456000123456009123456780001234000"));
// ["123456", "12345678", "1234"]

console.log(findSequential("12"));
// ["12"]

console.log(findSequential("1212"));
// ["12", "12"]

console.log(findSequential("23"));
// []
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i have this code for you

```js
var str = "456000123456009123456780001234000";
var length = str.length;
var out= "";

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
 if(str[i] == 1){
  out += str[i];
  var j = i;
  do{  
   j++;
   out += str[j];
  } while(str[j + 1] > out[out.length - 1])
  out += " ";
 }
}

console.log(out); // Outputs: 123456 12345678 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple and short code

```js
s= "456000123456009123456780001234000"
    var p
    var r=''
    for(let n of s ){
      if(n==1||n-p==1){
        r+=n, p=n
        r.length>1&&r.charAt(r.length-1)==1?r=r.substring(0,r.length-1)+'-1':r
      }
    }
    console.log(r.split('-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive version that keeps track of the index and length of the current sequence until it actually needs to output it, then calls `substr`. (Also useful to easily convert to returning just the sequences' locations in the string.)

```js
function f(s, i=1, l=0){
  if (i == s.length)
    return l ? [s.substr(i-l, l)] : [];
    
  if (s[i] != Number(s[i-1]) + 1 && l)
    return [s.substr(i-l, l)].concat(f(s, i+1, 0));
    
  if (s[i] == 2 && s[i-1] == 1)
    return f(s, i+1, 2);
    
  return f(s, i+1, l ? l+1: 0);
}

var strs = [
  "456000123456009123456780001234000",
  "1212",
  "12",
  "23"
];

for (let s of strs){
  console.log(s);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(f(s)));
  console.log('');
}
```